# Pusher PHP Server not working

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, pusher

I've been trying to trigger events using the [Pusher PHP Server](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-php-server) but unable to do so. I've tried several solutions like i-e enabling cURL extension at my server environment but still no result.
I've been successfully able to trigger events using the event creator provided by Pusher Debug Console. Am i missing something?

Client Side Code Snippet (Subscribing channel & listening for events)

```
<head>
  <title>Pusher Test</title>
  <script src="//js.pusher.com/2.2/pusher.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    Pusher.log = function(message) {
      if (window.console && window.console.log) {
        window.console.log(message);
      }
    };

    var pusher = new Pusher('key');
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('test_channel');
    channel.bind('my_event', function(data) {
      alert(data.message);
    });
  </script>
</head>
```

Server Side Code Snippet (not working)

```
require('Pusher.php'); 
$app_id = 'xxx'; 
$app_key = 'xxx';
$app_secret = 'xxx';
$pusher = new Pusher($app_key, $app_secret, $app_id);
$data['message'] = 'hello world';
$pusher->trigger('test_channel', 'my_event', $data);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're saying the event creator works I'm assuming the client functionality is fine and the problem is either:

- The PHP code
- the interaction with the Web API via the Pusher PHP library.

### Checking the PHP code

Ensure error reporting is turned on and execute the code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require('Pusher.php'); 
$app_id = 'xxx'; 
$app_key = 'xxx';
$app_secret = 'xxx';
$pusher = new Pusher($app_key, $app_secret, $app_id);
$data['message'] = 'hello world';
$pusher->trigger('test_channel', 'my_event', $data);
```

What is the output of running the above code?

### Debug & Logging in the Pusher PHP library

If all is well with the code then I'd recommend you take a look at the **debug and logging** information that's provided by the the library:
https://github.com/pusher/pusher-php-server#debugging

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require('Pusher.php'); 
$app_id = 'xxx'; 
$app_key = 'xxx';
$app_secret = 'xxx';

class MyLogger {
  public function log( $msg ) {
    print_r( $msg . "<br />" );
  }
}

$pusher = new Pusher($app_key, $app_secret, $app_id);
$logger = new MyLogger();
$pusher->set_logger( $logger );

$data['message'] = 'hello world';
$result = $pusher->trigger('test_channel', 'my_event', $data);
$logger->log( "---- My Result ---" );
$logger->log( $result );
```

What is the output from running this code? It should be something like:

> Pusher: ->trigger received string channel "test_channel". Converting
>   to array. Pusher: curl_init(
>   http://api.pusherapp.com:80/apps/97748/events?auth_key=XXX&auth_signature=XXX&auth_timestamp=1419197439&auth_version=1.0&body_md5=XXX ) Pusher: trigger POST:
>   {"name":"my_event","data":"{\"message\":\"hello
>   world\"}","channels":["test_channel"]} Pusher: exec_curl response:
>   Array ( [body] => {} [status] => 200 ) 
>   ---- My Result --- 1

The above steps should provide you with everything you need in order to work out why things aren't working.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After Debug and Logging in the PHP Pusher Library i figured out that my time zone is creating problem. I've temporarily managed to solve problem by matching timestamp of my server environment with Pusher's API timestamp. Is there any general solution to overcome this problem of timezones? 
Following was the logging stack trace 
`Pusher: exec_curl response: Array ( [body] => {Timestamp expired. Given Timestamp (2014-12-22T07:27:17Z) not within 600s of server time (2014-12-22T06:27:20Z) } [status] => 401 )`
Again Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Qasim I have faced the same problem as you, please what to do to match Pusher's API timestamp ?